# Java with Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm working with parametrized queries in Neo4j. I have started with the Hello world program taken from http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html.

And I also tried with program from http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-cypher-java.html.

And in the program they have specified the target path. What do I need to specify for that path.

I have written the programs in Eclipse and want to run it but dnt find the way.
Can anyone please help me out in the steps to execute the query and print Hello World and also to pass the parameters and see the graph in the second program.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB_PATH is the path to your graph database. If your Neo4j database is located at c:\graphs\helloDb then DB_PATH=c:\graphs\helloDb
If there is no existing Neo4j database in that location, then one will be created for you when you run the program.

Running it Eclipse is the same as running any Java program from Eclipse.